# No visibility when extending function for a data class from its companion object

Tags: android, kotlin

Given the following data class:

```kotlin
data class Coords(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
    companion object CoordsOps {
        private val shiftTable: Map<Direction, Pair<Int, Int>> = mapOf(
            Direction.North to Pair(0, 1),
            Direction.East to Pair(1, 0),
            Direction.South to Pair(0, -1),
            Direction.West to Pair(-1, 0)
        )

        private operator fun Coords.plus(increment: Pair<Int, Int>): Coords =
            Coords(x + increment.first, y + increment.second)

        fun Coords.shift(direction: Direction): Coords = this + shiftTable.getValue(direction)
    }
}
```

I'm not able to use the extension function `shift()` from outside that object. I would like to use `Coords.shift(direction)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How come you're writing it as an extension function inside the companion object, instead of just as a normal method on the class? I don't know if there's any issue with having an extension like that (might need to do something to import it) but it seems like it's just complicating things!

Comment: [Declaring extensions as members](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members)

Comment: Try this: `with(Coords.CoordsOps) { Coords(4, 1).shift(Direction.East) }` i.e. call shift when you're inside scope of ChoordOps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to. I copied your code exactly and was able to call extension function shift from another file.

Perhaps you're missing the import? Or calling it incorrectly? Try this

```
import <your_package>.Coords.CoordsOps.shift

val y = Coords(3, 4).shift(Direction.East)
```

Comment: My bad. I was calling `Coords` as a singleton. Please, don't judge me, it was too late at night. In fact, as @cactustictacs mentioned, I could have put the function directly in the data class –it can access private values and functions from the companion object. Thank you both!